# Excel: Find unique values in a column with criteria between sheets

Tags: excel

I've read many answers to similar questions but none I've seen satisfy my task, or I'm implementing it incorrectly.

I have two worksheets.

Worksheet 1:

Column A - a list of URLs

Column B - a list of anchor texts

Worksheet 2:

Column A - a list of URLs

In Worksheet 2, column B: I want to count the # of times there is a unique value in Worksheet 1, column B that corresponds to the URL in Worksheet 2, column A.

Is this possible?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by using a `pivot table` where first you select `rows = urls` and then `rows = text_excerpts`. After that, in values you should use '`count values of text`'.

Then you'll have a pivot table that looks like this one:

[image]

Note that the `url3`, that contains 2 times the `text1` and 1 time `text3`. In other hand, the `url7` contains 1x `text1` and 2x `text5`.

Comment: Hey, thanks - in the end pivot did the job fine. thanks very much!

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps the community to keep the focus on questions which still don't have answers.